# jQuery textarea value string with variables in one line

Tags: javascript, jquery

What i do wrong?

I need to set textarea value as string with variables i one line, but now with such code:

```
  $('#a1').val(currentVal + '[quote author="' + comment_author + '" date="' + comment_date + '"]' + comment_text + '[/quote]');
```

it generate me value with new lines, like:

```
               [quote author="
                  Гость
                " date="
                  23.02.14 11:26
               "]

                  sometextgoeshere
               [quote]
```

how to set it in one line? without line-breaking?

**upd:**  just  this part:

```
'[quote author="' + comment_author + '" date="' + comment_date + '"]' + comment_text + '[/quote]'
```

must be without line break.
just that line break's in text (comment) must be with line break, only separated part's like '[quote author="' + comment_author  must be in same line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var newVal = currentVal + '[quote author="' + comment_author.trim() + '" date="' + comment_date.trim() + '"]' + comment_text.trim() + '[/quote]'
//var newVal = newVal.replace(/\s|\n|\r|\t+/g, ' ');
$('#a1').val( newVal);
```

Comment: just that line break's in text (comment) must be with line break, only separated part's like '[quote author="' + comment_author  must be in same line

Comment: maybe i know in what is troube: i have such html:
                      `<span class="nick">
                          Гость
                        </span>`
and i need to fetch only text from this span, without new lines, spaces before and after text etc

Comment: in this case u can use trim function like comment_author.trim() .. editing the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can set `wrap` attribute to `off`:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3aB92/)

```
<textarea id="a1" wrap="off"></textarea>
```